# When is a clustered index absolutely necessary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database, clustered-index

AFAIK SQL table indices are to improve queries speed, so are not absolutely necessary. However SQL Azure for whatever reason demands that each table has a clustered index, so I guess there're cases when an index is necessary.

What can be a case when a clustered index is absolutely required and why?

Comment: It's a good, common practice to **have** a **good** clustering key (e.g. on an `INT IDENTITY`). Almost all operations are **faster** on a clustered table vs. a heap table. See [Kimberly Tripp's blog post](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absence of a clustered index implies a completely different storage model for the table, namely a *heap table*. I suspect that the SQL Azure team simply didn't implement this, and therefore tables must be stored in the "regular" way.

[This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1254/clustered-tables-vs-heap-tables/) describes some of the pros and cons of heap tables and clustered tables.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure requires clustered indices because of the replication on the back-end of the system. Here's a reference article from the MSDN blog that goes into some of the technical details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/12/10011257.aspx